# PHP CSS external file not working

Tags: php, css

The image below (at the very bottom) is the file structure for the site I'm building, where I can't connect the CSS file properly.

In directory Public/Admin/ there is a file login.php. From login.php, I use the following function call...

to get the header for the login.php page.

The function it calls in the (Includes/functions.php file)  is this

```
function include_layout_template($template=""){
include(SITE_ROOT.DS.'public'.DS.'layouts'.DS.$template);
}
```

which gets the admin_header.php file from the LAYOUT directory. I know the admin_header.php is loading properly into the login.php file using this function call because the html of the admin_header.php file is appearing when i load login.php. However, the admin_header.php file also has the link to the main.css file in the StyleSheets directory

```
<link href="../stylesheets/main.css" media="al" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Although, as mentioned, admin_header.php is being incorporated into public/Admin/login.php, the stylesheet is not working.

Looking at the directory structure below, is there something wrong with my link to the stylesheet?

[image: Picture of file structure]

Comment: Check out the link to the style sheet inside the document's source code using Chrome or Firefox. The link is clickable there. If you get a 404 in return, it is broken

Comment: @pekka how do I do that? can you please explain a bit more. thank you.. I'm a newbie

Comment: use the browser's "View source" function, the shortcut should be Ctrl + U in both browsers (not 100% sure because of international differences in layout.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the relativity of the file location that is your problem. You have `media="al"` when it should be `media="all"`. This should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The stylesheet's URL is relative to the generated HTML file, not the PHP file. I usually solve this by using absolute URLs, which means storing the base URL of the site somewhere (probably a configuration file) and then include all JS/CSS file like this:

```
<?php echo BASEURL ?>/css/style.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are in your public folder after one ../ and your include folder is at the same level. You need to step up one step more.. /../

Answer (score -2):

Simple trick is that if you rename the css file by SAVE AS option and create link for it. It will definitely work.

Comment: Why should the file be renamed? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn fro mit